# Jquery, On one click when using delegated events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question I haven't been able to solve myself, I know you guys can help me.

I have a div that contains dynamically generated content, to be precise it generates squares with content inside, each square has a cross icon so it can disappear and do some other stuff, the thing is that the square takes its time to fade out and it can be clicked more than once and it's causing me problems because it decreases a counter I declared more times than it should and messes up with other code :(

Here is my code:

```
$("#yha-tools").on("click", ".close", function (){
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
    cnr--;
});
```

I tried to use  `$("#yha-tools").one` but it doesn't help me meet my goal.

Comment: So you want each button to be clicked only once?

Comment: Can you please share your HTML

Comment: That's the goal @AdamAzad :)

Comment: you can try `.off()` http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this statement before the `fadeOut()`:

```
$(this)[0].style.pointerEvents = "none"
```

### Demo

```js
var cnr = 6;

$("#yha-tools").on("click", ".close", function() {
  $(this)[0].style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  $(this).fadeOut(500);
  cnr--;
  $('output').text(cnr);
});
```

```css
.close {
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}

output {
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Consolas;
}
```

```html
<section id='yha-tools'>
  <div class='close'>+</div>
  <div class='close'>+</div>
  <div class='close'>+</div>
  <div class='close'>+</div>
  <div class='close'>+</div>
  <div class='close'>+</div>
</section>
<output>6</output>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked perfect, it's short and easy to implement. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how many buttons you have, but you can certainly make use of `.data()` in this case. You can check if the element has not been clicked yet and processed with desired action.

```js
$("#yha-tools").on("click", ".close", function (){
 
    var clicked = $(this).data('clicked'); // This will `undefined` in the first run.
    
    if( ! clicked || clicked != true ){ // If element has not been clicked 

        $(this).fadeOut(500);
        
        $(this).data('clicked', true); 
        
        // do whatever else you want here.
    
    } 
    
    console.log( clicked );
    
});


$('[data-action="addBtn"]').on('click', function(){

    $("#yha-tools").append('<button class="close">Close me!</button>');

});


$('[data-action="showBtns"]').on('click', function(){
    $('.close').show();
});
```

```css
#yha-tools {
   padding: 10px;
   margin:10px;
   border:2px solid #ddd;
}
.close {
   margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yha-tools"></div>
<button data-action="addBtn">Add button</button>
<button data-action="showBtns">Show all buttons</button>
```